# How to trigger lsp suggestion popup in neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin, nvim-lspconfig, nvim.cmp

I'm using nvchad neovim setup with typescript lsp. Lsp works just fine and opens me list with suggestions to autocomplete, but only when I start typing something. What I want to be able to do is to trigger this suggestions list to pop up by pressing some hotkey

There is how it looks like

[No typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scPBR.png)

[Started typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uztXz.png)

I don't know if it useful, but I use next plugins for lsp:

- nvim-lspconfig
- mason.nvim
- mason-lspconfig.nvim

Also nvchad configuration has auto setup for nvim-cmp and LuaSnip plugins. I didn't configure them manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NvChad, autocompletion is <C-Space> (Control + Space) [by default](https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad/blob/v2.0/lua/plugins/configs/cmp.lua#L76C1-L76C44)

[nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp) is responsible for autocompletion.

If you want to change the default mapping, you have to add custom plugin options in NvChad ([source](https://nvchad.com/docs/config/plugins)):

- custom/chadrc.lua

```lua
M.plugins = "custom.plugins"
```

- custom/plugins.lua

```lua
local plugins = {
  -- this opts will extend the default opts 
  {
    "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    opts = {
      mapping = {
        ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(), -- Replace with whatever you want
      },
    },
  },
}

return plugins
```

*NOTE: This is true only to NvChad. For configuring with any other neovim config, consult the documentation.*

I recommend creating your own config instead of using a ready-made distribution like NvChad. It gives you a deep understanding of neovim configuration. If you don't know where to start, check out [kickstart.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Missed that `cmp.mapping.complete()` mapping in `configs/cmp.lua`